# Microsoft 2008 server batch file If Statement failure

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2008

I have created a batch file which automatically changes a uses session variable when they log on to the machine.

My original code works fine on a windows 7 machine. The code works great on a windows server 2008 machine until I get to the last if statement which is in a sub routine:

```
if /I "%1"=="Device" ( set stringfile=%results% ) else ( set stringfile=%* )
echo %stringfile%>> "C:\Temp location\temp.txt"
```

the routine works until it reaches the true statement, then it crashes. I am quite perplexed about this issue. The %results% value is assigned beforehand

Any assistance would be great.

Comment: crashes how? This isn't enough code to troubleshoot effectively.

Comment: the process ends. I am unsure of how to capture the failure, even if I echo out a static variable, it just quits. Is there a way to capture this failure?

Comment: Sure. comment out the `@echo off` at the top of your script or do it in strategic locations so you can see what is going on behind the scenes. I usually comment out my `@echo off` and pipe the script to a file so I can browse through it and find the errors.

Comment: the cmd.exe closes when the statement is true. I can only display the %1 parameter before the code is executed and the full call to the sub routine with all of the parameters. I am unsure of how to capture it. If I stick a set before it, I am able to pass through the if statement, but then again the if statement does not function correctly and will not produce the right code.

Comment: Are you double-clicking the file to run it?

Comment: yes, but I have also tried right clicking and choosing "Open" and I have also right clicked and choose "run as administrator". To no avail, the code will stop echoing on the screen once the if statement is true.

Comment: Ok. Don't double click it to run. Run it from a CMD prompt without @echo off. You'll see all of the output including the values of the variables. If there are any error messages, you'll see them too.

Comment: thank you!!! Ok, it says "in was unexpected at this time". on that line there happens to be a keyword of "in" and there are parentheses. how do I prevent this from being an issue or any other keywords?

Comment: I'd need to see the rest of your script to figure that out.

Comment: for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("C:\File path\file.txt") do  (CALL :storetext %%a)                :storetext                                                              if /I "%1"=="Device" ( set stringfile=%results% ) else ( set stringfile=%* )
echo %stringfile%>> "C:\Temp location\temp.txt"

Comment: the input string is as follows: "Device name=generic / text only (from ahsdndf-pc) in session 2"

Comment: found out I needed setlocal enableDelayedexpansion and change the input parms to the function and changed the set stringfile=%* to set "stringfile=%*" it seems to work now. Thank you for your help!